# Apache LB and huge amount of close_wait connections

Tags: apache-2.2, tcp

I use apache as a loadbalancer for servers with some java apps. On the apache host I saw huge number of close_wait state which was around 2500. Is it a problem with apache itself or with app on the other side?

RHEL 7.9
apache 2.2.15

Comment: Can you please share your kernel paremeters and distribution you use?

Comment: I have updated my question but what kernel parameters did you mean?

Comment: This question has been asked here too with a good explaination: https://serverfault.com/questions/160558/how-to-not-get-so-many-apache-close-wait-connections/346352

Comment: I have read it before but I don't understand "It then waits in this state for the local application to close()". What is local application in my case? Is it apache? Is apache responsible for not sending FIN to application server?