# Apache keeps TCP Connection in CLOSE-WAIT state for 600 Seconds

Tags: iptables, tcp, apache2, conntrack, nf-conntrack

My setup consists of two apache servers like in this diagram:

```
|Apache | >==Reverse Proxy Connection====> |Apache |
|Server1| <==Response through conntrack==< |Server2|
```

After a successful HTTP connection from *Server 1* to *Server 2*, the latter sends a `TCP [FIN,ACK]` packet.

This packet is properly acknowledged by *Server 1* with a `TCP [ACK]` packet. The connection is now in the `CLOSE-WAIT` state.

Then, almost 600 Seconds later, *Server 1* sends `TCP [FIN,ACK]` to *Server 2*, which responds with `TCP [RST]`.

This packet is marked by conntack as 'invalid' and never makes it to *Server 1* (due to an iptables rule), resulting in *Server 1* retransmitting the `TCP [FIN,ACK]` packet more than 20 times. This is because nf_conntrack has a timeout of 60 seconds for a TCP connection in the `CLOSE-WAIT` state.

[Packet Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkz6d.png)

- Why does Apache keep the TCP connection in the close-wait state for that long and why does the counterpart respond with RST?

Comment: You may find a part of your answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/160558/how-to-not-get-so-many-apache-close-wait-connections) and in the comments there is another serverfault page that expands on it.